# Basic HTML.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a viewmodel defined as

```
public class linkVM
{
    public AL.Common.Content.Object.PageIndex[] pages{ get; set; }
    public string sPageId { get; set; }
}
```

In a strogly typed form I am using

<%Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.pages, new SelectList(Model.pages, "PageId", "ShortName", Model.sPageId ));%>

I get a compile error on the SelectList(Model.pages, portion which says
'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Model'

There is clearly a chunk of basic knowledge I am missing - can anyone enlighten me please

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    n => n.sPageId, 
    new SelectList(Model.pages, "PageId", "ShortName")
) %>
```

Also make sure that your view is strongly typed to this `linkVM` class (the `@Page` directive at the top):

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<AL.MgrSite.ViewModel.content.linkVM>" %>
```

Also the controller action that rendered this view needs to pass the correct model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new linkVM 
    {
        // TODO: fetch those from your repository
        pages = new[]
        {
            new PageIndex { PageId = "1", ShortName = "name 1" },
            new PageIndex { PageId = "2", ShortName = "name 2" },
            new PageIndex { PageId = "3", ShortName = "name 3" },
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Also the convention in C# is to have class name and property names start with a Capital letter.

Comment: My page directive contains: Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<AL.MgrSite.ViewModel.content.linkVM>" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderContent" runat="server">

Comment: I have made the changes you suggest but still get the same error

Comment: If you do exactly as in my code snippet you won't get any errors. Try creating a new controller containing a single action with the code I proposed and a simple view containing only the call to the helper. Also verify that by any chance you don't have a class named `Model` which could conflict.

Comment: OK - I was converting this and my code was still wrapped in a HTML.BeginForm - if I remove this it seems to work ok - is this what you would expect ?